# js: hand generated text to next site

Tags: javascript, html

i use this js code to generate text:

```
let green, display, button, clock, end;
green = ["x", "t", "g", "l"];
display = ["l", "h", "r", "e"];
button = ["e", "D", "l", "w"];
clock = ["o", "b", "a.", "e"];
end = ["T", "g", "t", "w"];

function randGen() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
}

function sentence() {
  let rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    
  let content = clock[rand1] + " " + display[rand1] + " " + button[rand1] + " " + green[rand1] + " " + end[rand1];

  document.getElementById('sentence').innerHTML = "&quot;" + content + "&quot;";
};
sentence();
```

and put it in html like this:

```
<button style="" onclick="sentence()">generate text<i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

        <div class="container">
            <p id="sentence"></p>
        </div>
```

Now i want to use the generated text the user generates by hitting the "generate text"-button on another html-document. Is it possible? Do i need to safe this text anywhere before using it on another html-document?
thanks in advance
John

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. You have another HTML Page and you want to use what this generates on that?

Comment: What do you mean _"use on another HTML document"_ ? Can you explain more what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes, i have a second html page and want to use the generated text there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use localStorage to solve your problem.
Save your sentence to localStorage like this:

```
function sentence() {
  let rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    
  let content = clock[rand1] + " " + display[rand1] + " " + button[rand1] + " " + green[rand1] + " " + end[rand1];

  return content;
};

// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    localStorage.setItem("sentence", sentence());
}
```

And get sentence value on another page like this:

```
<div id="result"></div>
 
<script>
    // Check browser support
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("sentence");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Browser does not support Web Storage.";
    }
</script>
```

Hopefully, it will help your problem. Please let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: please check it solved once it helped you. thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, it works perfectly.
One further question: is it possible to show the generated text also on the first page where the "generate text" button is?